# Recover kubernetes-dashboard pod?

Tags: kubernetes-dashboard

I've installed kubernetes on Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS (Bionic Beaver). And now try to run the kubernetes-dashboard. However it keeps crashing.

```
NAME                                         READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
dashboard-metrics-scraper-7b59f7d4df-wj7ts   1/1     Running            0          153m
kubernetes-dashboard-74d688b6bc-2c6m6        0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   32         153m

$ kubectl logs kubernetes-dashboard-74d688b6bc-2c6m6 -n kubernetes-dashboard
2021/04/23 08:32:26 Using namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
2021/04/23 08:32:26 Starting overwatch
2021/04/23 08:32:26 Using in-cluster config to connect to apiserver
2021/04/23 08:32:26 Using secret token for csrf signing
2021/04/23 08:32:26 Initializing csrf token from kubernetes-dashboard-csrf secret
panic: Get https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/secrets/kubernetes-dashboard-csrf: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout

goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/src/app/backend/client/csrf.(*csrfTokenManager).init(0xc0004e69e0)
        /home/travis/build/kubernetes/dashboard/src/app/backend/client/csrf/manager.go:41 +0x446
github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/src/app/backend/client/csrf.NewCsrfTokenManager(...)
        /home/travis/build/kubernetes/dashboard/src/app/backend/client/csrf/manager.go:66
github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/src/app/backend/client.(*clientManager).initCSRFKey(0xc00047a080)
        /home/travis/build/kubernetes/dashboard/src/app/backend/client/manager.go:501 +0xc6
github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/src/app/backend/client.(*clientManager).init(0xc00047a080)
        /home/travis/build/kubernetes/dashboard/src/app/backend/client/manager.go:469 +0x47
github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/src/app/backend/client.NewClientManager(...)
        /home/travis/build/kubernetes/dashboard/src/app/backend/client/manager.go:550
main.main()
        /home/travis/build/kubernetes/dashboard/src/app/backend/dashboard.go:105 +0x20d
```

What did I miss or how can I recover from this?

Answer (score 0):

**TRY THE FOLLOWING**

- Check `kubectl get svc | grep kubernetes` and then `kubectl describe svc kubernetes` - Correct it if there is anything wrong here.
- Define Hostname In `/etc/hosts`

```
#vim /etc/hosts
YOUR_IP HOSTNAME
```

- Disable Firewall
- Restart Kubelet
- Restart Docker
- Flush IP Tables